# How to keep BackgroundService task receiving mqtt messages without Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mqtt, mqttnet

In my ASP.Net Core 6 application, a BackgroundService task called MqttClientService runs a MQTTNet client that handles incoming mqqt messages and responds with a message to indicate it was successful.

I have gotten [the sample console app from the MQTTNet repo](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Samples/Client/Client_Subscribe_Samples.cs) to work using `Console.ReadLine()`, however this feels like a hack for my use case. Is there a better way to keep the BackgroundService handling incoming messages without restarting constantly?

There is [an example with Asp.Net Core and MQTTNet version 3](https://github.com/rafiulgits/mqtt-client-dotnet-core), but it uses handles implemented by interfaces rather than async events that the library now uses: [the MQTTNet's Upgrading Guide](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/wiki/Upgrading-guide).

Any information will be appreciated, thank you.

MqttClientService.cs in Services/

```
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using System.Text;

namespace MqttClientAspNetCore.Services
{
    public class MqttClientService : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Handle_Received_Application_Message();
            }
        }

        public static async Task Handle_Received_Application_Message()
        {

            var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();

            using (var mqttClient = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient())
            {
                var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithTcpServer("test.mosquitto.org")
                    .Build();

                // Setup message handling before connecting so that queued messages
                // are also handled properly. 
                mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += e =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("### RECEIVED APPLICATION MESSAGE ###");
                    Console.WriteLine($"+ Payload = {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload)}");

                    // Publish successful message in response
                    var applicationMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                        .WithTopic("keipalatest/1/resp")
                        .WithPayload("OK")
                        .Build();

                    mqttClient.PublishAsync(applicationMessage, CancellationToken.None);

                    Console.WriteLine("MQTT application message is published.");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions, CancellationToken.None);

                var mqttSubscribeOptions = mqttFactory.CreateSubscribeOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithTopicFilter(f =>
                    {
                        f.WithTopic("keipalatest/1/post");
                        f.WithAtLeastOnceQoS();
                    })
                    .Build();

                await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(mqttSubscribeOptions, CancellationToken.None);

                Console.WriteLine("MQTT client subscribed to topic.");
                // The line below feels like a hack to keep background service from restarting
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using MqttClientAspNetCore.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHostedService<MqttClientService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// To check if web server is still responsive
app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    return "Hello World";
});


app.Run();
```

Comment: You don't need `Console.WriteLine` in the first place. That's only used to show that the *API* is running. It has nothing to do with the background service itself. You could remove `app.MapGet` completely, or use a generic instead of web host, with `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()`. The background service runs because `app.Run` was called. It will keep running until the application is terminated

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I was referring to the `Console.WriteLine` on the last line on the BackgroundService, not in Program.cs. I have removed it for clarity. Thanks. The purpose of `app.MapGet` is for me to make sure the server is still responsive, since the final goal is to have the background task running in parallel with a web server.

Comment: You don't need Console.WriteLine or ReadLine in the first place. [The service won't terminate if `ExecuteAsync` returns](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L39). You can set app the client and handler in `ExecuteAsync` without a loop.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how you can simplify the code, reducing `ExecuteAsync` to essentially two lines, and handle termination without awaiting the stop token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for Console.ReadLine or even the loop. The BackgroundService application code [won't terminate when ExecuteAsync returns](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L39). If you want the application to terminate when `ExecuteAsync` terminates you have to actually tell it to through the `IApplicationLifecycle` interface.

I've found this the hard way the first time I tried using a Generic host for a command line tool. Which seemed to hang forever ....

`ExecuteAsync` can be used to set up the MQTT client and the event handler and just let them work. The code terminates only when `StopAsync` is called. Even then, this is done by signaling a cancellation token, not by aborting some worker thread.

The client itself can be built in the constructor, eg using configuration settings. Only `ConnectAsync` needs to be called in `ExecuteAsync`.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{

    await _client.ConnectAsync(_clientOptions, CancellationToken.None);
    _logger.LogInformation("Connected");

    await _client.SubscribeAsync(_subscriptionOptions, CancellationToken.None);
    _logger.LogInformation("Subscribed");
}
```

The service code stops when [StopAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L61) is called and the cancellation token is triggered. `stoppingToken.Register` could be used to call `_client.DisconnectAsync` when that happens, but `Register` doesn't accept an asynchronous delegate. A better option is to override `StopAsync` itself :

```
public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _client.DisconnectAsync();
    await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

The constructor can create the client and register the message handler

```
public class MqttClientService : BackgroundService
{
    ILogger<MqttClientService> _logger;
    IMqttClient _client=client;

    MqttClientOptions _clientOptions;
    MqttSubscriptionOptions _subscriptionOptions;    
    string _topic;

    public MqttClientService(IOptions<MyMqttOptions> options, 
                            ILogger<MqttClientService> logger)
    {
        _logger=logger;
        _topic=options.Value.Topic;
        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        _client = factory.CreateMqttClient();
        _clientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                        .WithTcpServer(options.Value.Address)
                        .Build();
        _subscriptionOptions = factory.CreateSubscribeOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithTopicFilter(f =>
                    {
                        f.WithTopic(options.Value.Topic);
                        f.WithAtLeastOnceQoS();
                    })
                    .Build();
        _client.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += HandleMessageAsync;
    }
```

Received messages are handled by the `HandleMessageAsync` method :

```
async Task HandleMessageAsync(ApplicationMessageProcessedEventArgs e)
{
    var payload=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
    _logger.LogInformation("### RECEIVED APPLICATION MESSAGE ###\n{payload}",payload);
    var applicationMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                    .WithTopic(_topic)
                    .WithPayload("OK")
                    .Build();

    await _client.PublishAsync(applicationMessage, CancellationToken.None);

    _logger.LogInformation("MQTT application message is published.");
}
```

Finally, since `BackgroundService` implements `IDisposable`, we can use `Dispose` to dispose the `_client` instance :

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}

protected virtual Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(disposing)
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
    _client=null;
}
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly and is more correct for what I was trying to accomplish, thank you! To get it to work for me I changed `ApplicationMessageProcessedEventArgs` to `MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs` since I am not using the MQTTNet ManagedClient package, and added `void` to the `protected virtual Dispose(bool disposing) method`.

Answer (score 3):

If your service has nothing else useful to do, it can just wait for the `CancellationToken` to fire:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  try
  {
    await Handle_Received_Application_Message(stoppingToken);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}

public static async Task Handle_Received_Application_Message(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  ...
  Console.WriteLine("MQTT client subscribed to topic.");
  await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
}
```